# Add read_uri_permissions to share intent in Gluon Project

Tags: android, gluon, gluon-mobile

I'm trying to share an image and text with android intent ACTION_SEND:

```
 public void shareContent(String text, File image) {
    Item clipItem = new ClipData.Item(text);
    ClipData clipData = new ClipData(null, new String[] {}, clipItem);

    ClipboardManager clipBoardManager = (ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    clipBoardManager.setPrimaryClip(clipData);

    Uri pictureData = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,
                                                 "mypackage.fileprovider",
                                                 image);

    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("image/*");

    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pictureData);

    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share content..."));
}
```

When I add the FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSIONS to the intent, I get an PermissionDenied error, when the according picture is getting accessed.

I can make it work with:

```
 private void grantPicturePermissions(FXActivity context, Intent shareIntent, Uri pictureData) {
        List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);

        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
            String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
            context.grantUriPermission(packageName, pictureData, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        }
    }
```

But then I have to revoke all the granted permissions, when my app is resumed.
Is this an issue related to Gluon or what could be the reason?

(`shareIntent.setClipData(clipData)` didn't work either, thats why I had to use `clipBoardManager.setPrimaryClip(clipData)`)

Comment: Have you tried the Charm Down Share service? There is API for sharing both text and files. [Here](http://gluonhq.com/new-gluon-charm-services-part/) you can find a use case.

Comment: Yes I've had a look at the ShareService, but I need to access files that are private to my app, thats why I used the FileProvider in my code example.

Comment: The Gluon's Share service doesn't use `FileProvider`, so that permission is not required. The post I mentioned uses Storage service and a public location to access the file, so the required file is previously copied to that location. Your problems with FileProvider are an Android issue.